# how to import ajax get result to SQLite with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, sqlite, get

I develop a mobile app and I want to import the contents of a text file inside SQLite db.

I use the below code in order to read text file

```
function billtxt()
{
    var billjson = '{"posts" : [', 
        i, 
        line = 0,
        bill = 0,
        Amountint,
        Amountdec;

        jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
                     xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=iso-8859-7');
                },
        });

        jQuery.get('Bill.txt',function(data){
            alert(data.length);
            line=0;

            for (i = 1; i <= ((data.length)/156); i += 1) {
                billjson += '{"Id" :' + '"' + data.substr((line+0), 10).trim() + '"'  + ',';
                billjson += '"Code" :' + '"' + data.substr((line+10), 5).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
                billjson += '"Address" :' + '"' + data.substr((line+14), 40).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
                billjson += '"Name" : ' + '"'  + data.substr((line+54), 50).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
                billjson += '"Description" : ' + '"'  + data.substr((line+104), 8).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
                billjson += '"EntrySeason" : ' + '"'  + data.substr((line+112), 23).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
                billjson += '"Period" : ' + '"'  + data.substr((line+135), 11).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
                Amountint = data.substr((line+146), 7).trim();
                Amountdec = data.substr((line+153), 2).trim();
                billjson += '"Revenue" : ' + '"'  + Amountint + '.' + Amountdec + '"'  +  '}';
                line = i * 156;
                if (line == data.length)
                {
                    billjson += ']';
                }
                else 
                {
                    billjson += ',';
                }
            }

            if (line == 0)
            {
                billjson += ']';
            }


            billjson += "}";
            var mybilljson = jQuery.parseJSON( billjson );
        });
}
```

I convert the reading to JSON but i thing that this is not the appropriate solution...

What have to do for import the reading to SQLite?

Comment: Though I saw a question mark I'm having difficulties seeing the question in here...

Comment: I just dont know how to import the created json to SQLite